# Which browsers support XBAP at the moment?

Tags: browser, xbap

I know of IE8 and Firefox. Are there any others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct - at the moment only IE8 and Firefox support XBAP.

I just tested it on IE7 (just to confirm) and my browser spectacularly crashed.

Comment: I have had XBAP working fine on IE7 and it should also work in IE6 because XBPA support is not part of the browser as such.

Comment: I believe IE would support XBAP also for earlier versions, but what about other browsers?